# Convert ranges to other ranges

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It may be pretty basic but I am looking for an efficient way to convert a number with a range of **15-40** to another number in the range of `255-0`.

so at `x=15` I get `255` , and at `x=40` I get `0` .

Its linear .

Answer (score 0):

Any linear function of one variable is of the form y= ax+ b for some numbers a and b.  Here you want x= 15, y= 255 so 255= 15a+ b. You want x= 40, y= 0 so you have 0= 40a+ b.  It is easy to solve those two equations for a and b: subtracting the first  equation from the second eliminates b: 0- 255= (40- 15)a so 25a= -40, a= -40/25= -8/5.  Then 40a+ b= -64+ b= 0, b= 64.  The equation is y= -(8/5)a+ 64.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! If you want to convert a range $[a,b]$ to another range $[c,d]$ in a linear way, just use:

$$f(x) = c + (d-c)\times \frac{x-a}{b-a}.$$

The idea is that you compute where $x$ lies in the interval $[a,b]$ as a kind of percentage $(x-a)/(b-a)$. (So that $x=a$ corresponds to 0%, and $x=b$ corresponds to 100%). Then you compute where that percentage lies on the $[c,d]$ interval: $(d-c)\times(x-a)/(b-a)$. Finally, you add $c$ to that distance to obtain a range of numbers between $c$ and $d$.

---

In your case, you want to map $[15,40]$ into another range $[255,0]$. So you can use:

$$f(x) = 255 - 255 \times \frac{x-15}{40-15}$$

which we can use some algebra to simplify to:

$$f(x) = 255\times\left(\frac{40-x}{25}\right)$$

Answer (score -2):

```
let min:CGFloat=15
let max:CGFloat=50
let curve1=temp - min  // 0- 35
let delta=max-min

r = 255.0 - ( 255.0/delta)*curve1
```